# Tablename as Numeric in SQL Server using Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, tablename

I have the following code:

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=MY-PC;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True");
connection.Open();
 using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("CREATE TABLE Table1 (Weight INT, Name TEXT, Breed TEXT)", connection))
  {
     command.ExecuteNonQuery();
  }
 connection.Close();
```

Using this I am able to add a new table called "Table1". But as soon as I change the table name to only numbers, such as using `"CREATE TABLE 123456 (Weight INT, Name TEXT, Breed TEXT)"`.

I get

> SQLException: Incorrect syntax near '123456'.

How can I create a tablename with only numbers?

Comment: No you can't in many DB engines. At least a table name cannot start with a number mostly.

Comment: which database are you using ?

Comment: You cannot start with numeric value, one way is you can add suffix "tb_" or any alphabet while creating tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL-Server table names cannot start with a number. See the [Rules for Regular Identifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa223962%28v=sql.80%29.aspx).

> The first character [of an identifier] must be one of the following:
>
> - **A letter** as defined by the Unicode Standard 2.0. The Unicode definition of letters includes Latin characters from a through z and from A through Z, in addition to letter characters from other languages.
> - The underscore (_), "at" sign (@), or number sign (#).
>   Certain symbols at the beginning of an identifier have special meaning in SQL Server. An identifier beginning with the "at" sign denotes a local variable or parameter. An identifier beginning with a number sign denotes a temporary table or procedure. An identifier beginning with double number signs (##) denotes a global temporary object.
>   Some Transact-SQL functions have names that start with double at signs (@@). To avoid confusion with these functions, it is recommended that you do not use names that start with @@.

Answer (score 0):

In standard SQL,tables names that start with numbers are not allowed.You can start the name of the table with a letter and then you can use number.Note that dynamically creating a tables is a sign that you need to work on your database design.

Comment: But if your requirement remains the same then you can try this.
CREATE TABLE [47] 
(ID int,val varchar(150))
But using such dynamical names lowers the performance of your database.